# Faster Python alternatives to WebDriver's find_elements_by_(class_name | css_selector)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, lxml

For a typical eBay search results page such as [this](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?rt=nc&LH_Complete=1&_nkw=Mizuno%20Pants%20Baseball&LH_Sold=1&_sacat=0&LH_BIN=1&_from=R40&_sop=3&LH_ItemCondition=1000), I'm using WebDriver in Python to extract the price of each result thus:

```
PRICEELEMENT = 'ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)'
prices =  driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(PRICEELEMENT)]
```

Constructing `prices` sometimes takes up to **10 seconds**, with an average of 4 or 5. So does:

```
PRICEELEMENTCLASS = 'bidsold'
prices driver.find_elements_by_class_name(PRICEELEMENTCLASS)
```

Of course, then I have to go and get `.text` for each price, which adds even more time.

**What are better options here using `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` (or other)?**

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using eBay's API?  It is quite extensive.